# Does Gothic have /r/-umlaut and /x/-umlaut?

Tags: gothic, umlaut

Charles Nydorf believes that /r/-umlaut and /x/-umlaut in Yiddish come from /r/-umlaut and /x/-umlaut in Gothic, but he gives no examples in either language.

Yiddish has (/i/ >) /e/ > /a/ before /r/ or /x/.

Does Gothic have either of those phenomena and, if it does, what do Gothicists call it?

Umlaut is the replacement of one vowel by another vowel in the stem of a word that is triggered by a third vowel in the stem (primary umlaut) or in the ending or suffix of a word (secondary umlaut). It seems to me therefore that umlaut is not the proper term for the phenomena in question.

Comment: I agree that umlaut seems like a poor choice of word here, I'd probably describe this just as lowering. Claiming that the Yiddish case originates from Gothic seems pretty non-sensical though. Rhotics & /x/ both require a retracted tongue root which is something that often lowers neighbouring vowels. As Yiddish is a West Germanic language, and diverged from German long after Gothic went extinct (with the possibly exception of in Crimea), and independent development seems much more likely

Comment: as an example of a similar, but certainly independent development, Old English had i e æ > io eo ea before h (/x/ in at least some positions) or r/l followed by another consonant. Later vowel changes generally monophthongised these broken vowels, often lowering and/or them e.g. Proto-Germanic *lirnōjan > OE liornan > Modern English learn

Comment: Gold, David L. 2022. “No evidence even hints that Yidish was originally a variety of Gothic or that Gothic has influenced Yidish.” Etudes médiévales. Vols. 22-24. Pp. 127-158.